# Unable to start Ubuntu in GUI mode after upgrade

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, gui, fsck

I have upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.04, but when it restarted in graphical mode ...

[image]

[image: I tried to check filesystem]

Comment: Posts should be clear without the images, buddy.

Comment: @User1986 Sorry I cannot use this system that's why taken pictures and working on another computer. Is there anyway to copy paste this Ubuntu pc?

Comment: Best way is to probably use OCR